# Android Support Fragment namespace in MvvmCross 4.0

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm updating my using statements to use MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging now that MvvmCross 4.0 has been released.  I've added the package via NuGet and also referenced in my using statement per below.

```
using Android.Content;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;
using MvvmCross.Platform.Platform;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Views;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Platform;
using System.Reflection;
using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging;

namespace My.Droid
{
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new AN.Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
    {
        typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager).Assembly,
        typeof(MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging).Assembly,
    };

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        return new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    }
   }
}
```

VS 2015 is not locating the last library in my using statement despite it being added via NuGet.  Also, the MvxFragmentsPresenter namespace cannot be found.  Is there a different package to be used instead of the one referenced, or is there a different namespace that I should use to remedy the issue?

Comment: The namespace is [`MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Presenter`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a5d1a4bd667d57c3dc6d40a3ddbf50730414e6cf/MvvmCross/Droid/FullFragging/Presenter/MvxFragmentsPresenter.cs#L17) and you need [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging/) installed

Comment: If you use the support packages the namespace will not contain `FullFragging`